# Silverlight 4.0 - HttpWebRequest throwing ProtocolViolationException

Tags: silverlight, httpwebrequest, silverlight-4.0, get

I am getting a "System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." error when trying to call

```
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

 request.Method = "GET";

 request.ContentType = "text/xml";

 request.BeginGetRequestStream(RequestCompleted, request);
```

Comment: Upon inspecting the network traffic using Google Chrome's developer tools, i see that the clientaccesspolicy.xml hosted on the webserver's root is not retrived.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect this may be because you are performing a `BeginGetRequestStream` on a request object for which you have specified the "GET" method.

When performing a "GET" the server will not be expecting an entity body in the request hence you should proceed straight to `BeginGetResponse`.  Also specifying a `ContentType` on the request is not necessary, it specifies the type of content being sent in the entity body of the request but as stated a "GET" doesn't send any content it only gets content.

Comment: so what do I do with a PUT or DELETE then?

Comment: @cmaduro:  Well PUT (DELETE also doesn't have an entity body) is where you would use `BeginGetRequestStream` however you would nee to be using the ClientHTTP stack since the BrowserHTTP stack only supports GET and POST

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with AnthonyWJones answer. I find nothing in the HTTP spec that prohibits a "GET" request from containing a message body. I think this has unfortunately become the de facto understanding of how HTTP works since there is generally no need (or way) to include a message body. Having said that, he is correct as to the cause of this specific exception. However, I think the BCL should be changed to allow it.

If anyone can point it out I would be very interested to know where the spec precludes this:
[HTTP RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)